# Rails Destroy Record link doesn't do anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to destroy a nested record, the destroy button appears to work and redirect back to the above models page but the record still shows up there.

**Here is my partial for the nested record:**

```
<p>
    <tr>
        <td><%= time_delta.start %></td>
        <td><%= time_delta.length %></td>
        <td>
            <%=
                link_to 'Destroy Time Delta',
                [time_delta.stock, time_delta],
                method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
            %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</p>
```

**Heres the show for the above class**

```
<!-- Shows the stock-->
<h1> Stock </h1>
<table> 
    <tr>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Hashtag</th>        
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%= @stock.name %></td>
            <td><%= @stock.hashtag %></td>
        </tr>
</table>

<!-- Shows the Time Detlas-->
<h3>TimeDeltas: </h2>
<%= render @stock.time_deltas %>

<!-- Creates a Time Delta-->
<h3>Add a TimeDelta:</h2>
<%= render "time_deltas/form" %>

<%= link_to 'Back', stocks_path%>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_stock_path(@stock)%>
```

**Here is the controller for the Time Delta (The nested class)**

```
class TimeDeltasController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:stock_id])
    @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.create(time_delta_params)
    redirect_to stock_path(@stock)
  end

  def destroy
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:stock_id]) 
    @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.create(params[:time_delta_id])

    # @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.create(time_delta_params)
    @time_delta.destroy
    redirect_to stock_path(@stock)
  end

  private 
    def time_delta_params
      params.require(:time_delta).permit(:start, :length)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new time_delta on the action and calling destroy on it. What you need is find the time_delta which you want to destroy.
Change the second line in destroy action to:
 `@time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Why now `@time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.destroy(params[:id])`?